# On Ruby on Rails, where is "commands/server" which is required by script/server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails's `script/server` is just a few lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'commands/server'
```

I wonder where the `server` file is?  I tried a

```
find . -name 'server.*' 
find . -name 'server'
```

but can't find it

Answer (score 2):

You have to look for the files in your related gem repo.  Your Ruby is located at

```
which ruby
```

Your Rails gem is

```
bundle show rails
```

You can go to the dir with

```
cd `bundle show rails`/lib/commands
```

Then, open `server.rb`

Answer (score 0):

thanks.  in the case of a Mac, I found that they are on

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb
/Users/peter/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb
```

the following are there but doesn't have my Rails 2.3.5 version:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-1.2.6/lib/commands/server.rb       
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb
```

**Update:** Now the question is: which of the above 3 is the one?  How can you tell easily?

Comment: This is only if you are using the version of Rails that comes bundled with the machine. Basically, it's what Chris said above, it will be in the `lib/commands` directory of whichever Rails gem is being used in the project.

Comment: Also, it's probably in the System Ruby framework (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework`).

Answer (score 0):

In linux they are more likely to be under

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/ruby_version/gems/rails_version/lib/commands
```

ruby_version and rails_version depends on which versions you are using. The directory structure will also depend on whether or not you are using rvm, but hopefully you can find your way once you get to the `/usr/lib/ruby/` directory